# background size not working on mozila

Tags: php, html, css

I want to sent body background image with full width and i have done this with your previous questions and answer but i have faced a problem with mozila browser the image is not set with full width.
This is my code which i am writing in css file..

```
background-image: url("/images/newimages/loginimage.jpg");
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

This work fine on chorme browser but not working on mozila i do not what going wrong with my code.

Here is link for checking http://officemachine.mobi/login/index.php
check this link on both browser.

Comment: BTW Do you know, that this background is f***** huge and it takes 20 seconds to load it?

Comment: yes i know it too large image, but who care for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS. Should work.

```
html{
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Same answer at the same time :) Do you know if there is better to set it to html than on body for some reason?

Comment: yeah! some times if you don't have content which will not take 100% of the body height, it'll only stretch until the content height. setting html height to 100% will take up the entire browser height.

Comment: Yes, but I mean - is there a different of 100% height on html or on body element? I usually don't set css on html because it's the document and it just doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0):

It's because 100% height is the height of the body, and the body is not that high. Try adding:

```
body { height: 100%; }
```